# How to transfer my wallet.dat to dedicated Ubuntu server

Tags: bitcoind, wallet-import

Sorry for dummy question at first.

I have developed an application on my local dev machine. Now I want to make a realease on production server located elsewhere to which I have ssh access.

I dont want to put my wallet.dat in git. Of course.
But dedicated server doesnt have access to my local virtual ubuntu developer machine where wallet.dat is kept.

So I have to copy my wallet.dat from one virtual machine it terminal to another terminal. I thought I could dump keys to some text file and simply copypast it between servers. But `dumpwallet` command creates file with hundreeds of addresses and each one of them should be than imported on by one by `importprivkey` and there is no option to import dumped file (weird, no?)

Answer (score 1):

Though not really bitcoin related...
How are the two systems connected? I mean, can you already login via ssh? Or do you only have a terminal running on both, and no ssh daemon?

If no ssh daemon, then netcat is the tool of choice. 
If ssh daemon is running, use secure copy tool:

```
scp -port source target
```

e.g.:

```
scp -P 22022 ~/.bitcoin/wallet.dat 192.168.92.117:/home/mybitcoinuser/.bitcoin
```

And lastly, if the target server doesn‘t run ssh daemon, you can for sure start one in your terminal, and execute the scp from the target server (adopting the source and target).

There is a capital P when using scp.

Comment: Ah, just re-read question. you have ssh, so the first approach with scp should work...

Comment: I do have ssh access to the remote server. But my virtual server where dev site is running - does not. My host machine is windows, so I can copy wallet.dat from my dev server to windows, but cant copy it to remove target server since to connect I use putty ssh manager and it doesnt have an access to my windows files.

Comment: ahh, windows... and you have 3 machines involved... I am not clear: a windows host, with a virtual dev machine, and a remote server. And you want to send from Windows to the virtual machine or to remote server? I remember, that using pscp.exe was the tool, which allows to send files to a remote machines from a windows box...

Comment: `pscp.exe` doent even start :(

Comment: Ok, now it gets more and more complicated, and doesn’t add value to the bitcoin community. Probably you need to find the software, get it installed, and maybe look into the Windows areas on further howto...